# Packer dedicated provisioners for builders

Tags: packer

I have two builders in packer template - "azure-arm" and "amazon-ebs",
Is it possible to have dedicated provisioner for each builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `only` and `except` options in a provisioner section to control for which builders it gets executed.

Example:

```
{ 
   "type": "shell",
   "script": "script.sh",
   "only": ["virtualbox-iso"]
 }
```

See [Packer documentation](https://packer.io/docs/templates/provisioners.html#run-on-specific-builds)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for multiple "azure-arm" builders - https://prnt.sc/qrufth but it seems to be an issue with Azure API

Comment: Could you please share that link with me? I couldn't find anything(